# Copying creatives while preserving line item associations in DFP/GAM

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager, double-click-advertising

I have thousands of line items in GAM that have 3 associated creatives. However, we are adding more ads on the page, so now we need more creatives. What I'd like to do is simply duplicate the creatives I already have. However when I do this, the line item association is not preserved, so I would need to manually associate each new creative with thousands of line items individually. This feels ridiculous. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add line items to each of your 3 creatives :

```
> go to "Delivery"
> then "Creatives"
> select one of the creative you want to duplicate and "Copy" it
> click on it and go to "Associations"
> click on "Add line items"
> select all of your line items
```

if your line items all belong to the same campaign or advertiser, it might be straigh forward.

Documentation [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/3187916?hl=en)